# How do I map the action to pressing a +i?

Tags: karabiner

I am using this modification: [Mouse keys Ambidextrous](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#mouse_keys_ambi).

I have a problem because I want to control the cursor not by <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, but by <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Below is the code. When I change `left_control` to `a`, it doesn't work. Why?

```
"from": {
     "key_code": "i",
     "modifiers": {
         "mandatory": [
             "left_control"
         ],
         "optional": [
             "any"
         ]
     }
 },
 "to": [
     {
         "mouse_key": {
             "y": -4072
         }
     }
 ],
 "type": "basic"
}
```

Comment: Yyou want to press the a key and the i key together to move the mouse?

Comment: @nohillside, yes, exactly. What can I do about that?

Comment: Not sure this is even possible, character keys are not modifier keys. Are there any examples on the website for actions based on two character keys?